# way to share a models.py file between different modules?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a GAE app with multiple modules, each in their own folder like so:

```
/app_root
    app.yaml
    /module_1
        module_1.yaml
    /module_2
        module_2.yaml
    /module_3
        module_3.yaml
```

Each module right now has their own `models.py` file, but some modules access the same datastore kinds, and if I change the kind, I have to manually update the `models.py` files in each module (as necessary). Is there a way to do something like this instead:

```
/app_root
    app.yaml
    /models
        models.py
        __init__.py
    /module_1
        module_1.yaml
        get_index_size.py
        __init__.py
    /module_2
        module_2.yaml
        __init__.py
    /module_3
        module_3.yaml
        __init__.py
```

And do relative imports? From within one of my modules I tried this piece of code:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
```

To add the parent directory, but then I get an `ImportError` when I try:

```
from models import models
```

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/[app_id]/search:main.377708108929972632/get_index_size.py", line 13, in <module>
from models import models
```

It seems the folder structure is different on App Engine then it is locally, so while I can append the path and import on my `dev_appserver`, I can't do it in production. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an `__init__.py` file to your models folder. That way Python knows it is a namespace.

Comment: Just tried it and it didn't work -- should there be anything in the `__init__.py` file? Thanks.

Comment: Where are you calling your import from? `__init__.py` can be empty.

Comment: Updated my question with that information -- basically I'm trying to import from a script in a module, say in this case, `module_1`. Thanks.

Comment: Add an `__init__.py` to `module_1` so Python knows it's a package. Then you should be able to import back and forth.